# How to create a static constant member std::string array?

Tags: c++, static, constants, member

I cannot believe that something that sounds so simple can be so hard.

```
class OutputHandler {
private:
    static std::string const errorPrefixes[] = {"INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR", "CRASH"};
};
```

How do I do this properly? From various documentations I understand that I cannot initialize Static Member Objects, regardless of them being constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the initialization outside the class, together with the definition:

```
class OutputHandler
{
private:
    static std::string const errorPrefixes[];
};

std::string const OutputHandler::errorPrefixes[] = {"INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR", "CRASH"};
```

(The definition is of course subject to the one-definition-rule and must only appear in one single translation unit, e.g. `OutputHandler.cpp`.)

Comment: This is literally the only way to do it? (Like it cannot be done automatically when loading the application without any code outside the class definition? )

Comment: @Binero: every object (which is odr-used) must be defined. There's no way around that.

Comment: @Binero: Why don't you have an array of `const char *` instead?

Comment: Because `error: in-class initialization of static data member 'const char* OutputHandler::errorPrefixes []' of incomplete type`

Code: `static char const* errorPrefixes[] = {"INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR", "CRASH"};`

Comment: This did it for me. Thanks `static constexpr char const * const arr[] = {"INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR", "CRASH"};`

Comment: @Binero: With C++11, you *can* initialize a constexpr array inline, but you still need to provide a definition: [Example](http://ideone.com/8MEhkE).

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize your `static` members in a source file to satisfy the [one-definition-rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule):

```
// in .h
class OutputHandler {
private:
    static std::string const errorPrefixes[]; // declaration
};

// in .cpp
// definition
std::string const OutputHandler::errorPrefixes[] = {"INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR", "CRASH"};
```